# OpenCVでカメラ角度を取得したい

Tags: opencv

固定されたカメラがあります。
このカメラは角度は変えることができます。（よくある監視カメラ）
このカメラで角度を変えて違った画像１，画像２があります。
画像１と画像２のX方向の角度、Y方向の角度を求めたいです。
OpenCVなど（それ以外でもいいですが）角度を取得することはできるでしょうか？

エピポーラー幾何（epipolar geograpy）とは逆？のパターンになるかとおもいますが、角度を求める方法はありますか？
教えていただきたいです。

Comment: OpenCVにある関数を無理矢理(?)使うなら，「`findEssentialMat`→`decomposeEssentialMat`→自分が欲しい角度」という手順とかがありそうですが，正直面倒そうなので自前の算出コードを書いた方が早い気が．

Answer (score 0):

２つの画像から、同じ点(例えば同じ人の鼻の頭)の位置が検出できれば、2つの画像をとった時のカメラの向きの差分を求めることは可能ではないかと思われますが、撮られた画像次第でしょうね。
（(同じ点が映っている)画素の位置が特定できれば、光学系にどの方向から光が入ったかが分かりますから、カメラの向きに相対的な方向が決まります。そうした情報が２つあれば、カメラの向きの差が求められるはずです）

（二つの画像が全く異なる向きのカメラで撮られた（画像１と画像２に共通して映っている物がない）場合には、不可能）

Comment: 「カメラの視野内に映っていない物」としては消失点が利用可能かと思います（もっとも，それを用いた推定を行えるシーンというのはかなり限定的でしょうが）．